# Hard coded buttons do not appear in design view, or in the running program

Tags: java, eclipse, forms, swing

Whenever I choose to hard code an object (so far, I have sampled buttons, text fields and comboboxes), it does not appear on the associated form. Is there a separate piece of code that handles this, or can I use the following? Additionally, are layout bonds *strictly* necessary?

```
JButton startButton = new JButton("Start for loop ex");
    startButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0){
        int start = 1;
        int end = 5;
        int answer = 0;

        for (int i = start; i < end; i++){
            answer = answer + i;
        }           
    };
```

IDEOne showing the entirety of the code: 
http://ideone.com/u7CuoG

Comment: *"Additionally, are layout bonds **strictly** necessary?"* If you have the smarts to correctly account for the size and position of all GUI elements, implement that logic in a custom layout. So ..yes.

Comment: BTW - I don't see how reacting to a button action has anything to do with layouts..

Comment: @AndrewThompson I'm not quite sure I follow what you're getting at in the second comment, but I thought there may have been a default size and position that an object would default to.

Comment: Where did you add the Button and what is the layout of the container that the Button to be added into?

Comment: @BahramdunAdil I have added a fiddle to show the entirety

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you only created the button, but forgot to put it in the `JFrame`.

Assuming that `this` is a subclass of `JFrame`, you can do this to add the button to the frame:

```
this.add(startButton);
```

Also check if you have called `setContentPane`. If you have not, the button will fill up the whole frame.

It is only natural that dynamically added buttons don't appear in the design view because it would be very slow to compile and run your code every time you open the design view!

EDIT:

I ran the code you gave me and produced this frame. As you can see, the button is on the frame:

[image]

Comment: 'Sample1()' is the immediate subclass of 'JFrame', and subsequently the button is a subclass of that. However, 'this.add(startButton);' failed to produce any difference. Here is a "fiddle" of sorts: http://ideone.com/u7CuoG

Comment: @Wolfish See my edited answer. You missed a `)` in the fiddle.

Comment: So I did! Thanks a lot for the help.